# Store CMTimeRange into Core Data

Tags: datetime, objective-c, interval, core-data

I wanted to store `CMTimeRange` structures inside managed objects, so I've worked out the following:

```
@interface Clip : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * primitiveRange;
@property CMTimeRange range;

@end
```

Within the data model editor I've set the type of `primitiveRange` to "Transformable".

The implementation:

```
@implementation Clip
{
    CMTimeRange _range;
}
@dynamic primitiveRange;

// pre-calculated get    
- (void)awakeFromFetch
{
    [super awakeFromFetch];

    NSData *data = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"primitiveRange"];
    if (data) {
        _range = CMTimeRangeMakeFromDictionary((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]);
    }
}

- (CMTimeRange)range
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"primitiveRange"];
    CMTimeRange value = _range;
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"primitiveRange"];

    return value;
}

// immediate-update set
- (void)setRange:(CMTimeRange)range
{
    NSData *value = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeRangeCopyAsDictionary(range, kCFAllocatorDefault))];

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"primitiveRange"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:value forKey:@"primitiveRange"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"primitiveRange"];

    _range = range;
}
```

This works fine, but is this the proper way of doing things?

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C doesn't have namespaces.  As such, we need to be much more careful with our class names.  The common way for dealing with this problem in Objective-C is to come up with a 2 or 3 letter prefix to put in front of all of your classes.  Apple does this with their classes.

- `NS` for NeXTSTEP
- `CF` for CoreFoundation
- `UI` for UserInterface
- `SK` for SpriteKit
- `CM` for CoreMotion (but I think it overlaps something else maybe)
- `CA` for CoreAnimation
- `CG` for CoreGraphics

And there are more.

If it weren't for this naming convention, Apple would have a hard time creating class like `NSView` for OS X development and `UIView` for iOS development.

Following in this path, other good Objective-C developers come up with their own acronyms to prefix their various classes, structs, and typealiases with.  And you should do the same.  `Clip` just will not work as a class name (plus, it's not particularly expressive of what the class actually represents... is this like a movie clip or audio clip or something?).

---

I believe most Objective-C programmers prefer Egyptian braces.  You're consistent-ish with your braces though, that's fine-ish and not a necessary change.  I say consistent-ish because you use Egyptian braces for your `if`, but not for your methods.  Due to the way Xcode folds code, I consider Egyptian style to be vastly superior if you're developing in Xcode.

---

Finally... we often talk about (especially in Code Reviews), [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).  You don't have any of these, but I'm going to go ahead and call `@"primitiveRange"` a magic string.

We should define a constant, and perhaps use reverse domain lookup for your keys:

```
NSString * const kKEY_PrimitiveRange = @"com.yourDomain.clip.primitiveRange";
```

Your using this string in 6 places.  What happens if, for whatever reason, you decide to change the string?  Now you have to change it in 6 different places.  If we'd just use a string constant, if we ever change the string, we only have to change it in one place.